# Движение картинки в предложении

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.Piper{
   background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e9/2f/03/e92f03ace41d591e3c3f7454105dcffb.jpg);
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-family: Junegull;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
    
}
```

```html
  <div class="Piper">
   Картинка внутри текста 
  </div>
```

Нужно сделать,чтобы при прокрутки страницы вниз или вверх картинка внутри предложения "двигалась" но текст оставался на месте, как тут https://www.styleshout.com/templates/preview/Ceevee10/ перед формой регистрации, где сайт скроллится,но картинка остается на месте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e9/2f/03/e92f03ace41d591e3c3f7454105dcffb.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<div>
  Картинка внутри текста
</div>
<section></section>
```

Comment: Да,это то что нужно,спасибо вам,а не подскажите,возможно ли при таком эффекте сделать текст 3D с помощью `text-shadow` или чего то подобного?

Comment: filter: drop-shadow(val val val color) диву, если это ты об этом эффекте